# Count(*) differs from rows in sys.partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema

I'm using the following query to get information about all tables in a DB:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    i.name as indexName,
    sum(p.rows) as RowCounts,
    sum(a.total_pages) as TotalPages, 
    sum(a.used_pages) as UsedPages, 
    sum(a.data_pages) as DataPages,
    (sum(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 as TotalSpaceMB, 
    (sum(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 as UsedSpaceMB, 
    (sum(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 as DataSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
    i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
    i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
    t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name 
ORDER BY 
    object_name(i.object_id)
```

The problem is that for some tables it reports a different row count than if I do:

```
select count(*) FROM someTable
```

Why is that?

**Edit:**

The first query returns a higher count:

```
First: 1 240 464
Second:  413 496
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there's more than one allocation_unit per partition, so the same partition can appear more than once and therefore the sum(p.rows) ends up counting the same partition more than once, so you get a multiple of the right number of rows.

Here's how I solved the problem:
(note that my query isn't identical to yours, I have slightly different columns and used Kb rather than Mb, but the idea is the same)

```
    SELECT 
        s.Name + '.' + t.name AS table_name,
        (select sum(p2.rows)
            from sys.indexes i2 inner join sys.partitions p2 ON i2.object_id = p2.OBJECT_ID AND i2.index_id = p2.index_id
            where i2.object_id = t.object_id and i2.object_id > 255 and (i2.index_id = 0 or i2.index_id = 1)
        ) as total_rows,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.index_id=0) OR (i.index_id=1) THEN a.total_pages * 8 ELSE 0 END) AS data_size_kb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.index_id=0) OR (i.index_id=1) THEN a.used_pages * 8 ELSE 0 END) AS data_used_kb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.index_id=0) OR (i.index_id=1) THEN 0 ELSE a.total_pages * 8 END) AS index_size_kb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (i.index_id=0) OR (i.index_id=1) THEN 0 ELSE a.used_pages * 8 END) AS index_used_kb,
        SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS total_size_kb, 
        SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS total_used_kb,
        SUM(a.used_pages) * 100 / CASE WHEN SUM(a.total_pages) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(a.total_pages) END AS percent_full
    FROM 
        sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    INNER JOIN      
        sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    WHERE 
        t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
    GROUP BY 
        t.object_id, t.Name, s.Name
    ORDER BY SUM(a.total_pages) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the sys.partitions documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foo1c19e1b1-c925-4dad-a652-581692f4ab5e.aspx)

> rows bigint **Approximate number of rows in this partition.**

(emphasis mine). The system views aren't going to keep a spot-on number of rows in the table. Think of what that would entail and how much overhead it would add to all insert/delete statements. If I were a betting man, I'd say that it's doing something with the count of the number of pages in the clustered index or heap which is a far cheaper operation. That's purely speculative, though.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: it's true that the count is approximate, but the real problem is that the query is wrong because it causes the same partition's rows to be summed more than once, so you get the correct (if approximate) answer multiplied by however many allocation units exist.

Comment: There is a potential for double counting if a given partition has more than one AU (i.e. IN_ROW_DATA and LOB_DATA). An easy fix is to add a predicate to the original query for just IN_ROW_DATA or do an average over all AUs found. But to say that it's incorrect is a little strong; everything in my original answer is correct with respect to the row count in sys.partitions being an approximate value.

Comment: True that the information in your comment is correct, but given that the original question cites the query of sys.partitions as giving the answer as 1240464 when the actual count was 413496, the approximate nature of partitions.rows isn't the explanation for what the questioner was seeing. I upvoted your answer anyway because it's still good info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the help article regarding the `sys.allocation_units` view? Apparently, the `container_id` field is a little more than it seems. Try to add this to the `where` section:

```
and a.type = 2
```

Comment: This is the correct insight but not the correct solution. Because there can be more than one allocation_unit per partition, the same partition can appear more than once and therefore the sum(p.rows) ends up counting the same partition more than once.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016, To fix the `count(*)` and `sys.partitions` mismatch I performed an Index Rebuild on the Primary Key. Luckily the TABLE only had 2.4 million rows so it didn't take that long as I  have standard edition so couldn't do the rebuild ONLINE.

Answer (score -1):

Inner joins will cause unmatched rows to be filtered out. Groups will also affect your row counts as they can combine rows. These two conditions were cause a lower row count for the aggregate query than the simple count(*).

I see specifically you're asking about the sys.partitions table. The likely explanation is that there is not a match for every row in the sys.indexes table given the match condition of i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id. Try running this:

```
Select 
  count(*) 
from 
  sys.partitions p
LEFT JOIN
  sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
```

You will then likely see the count you expect. Remove the count function to simply `Select * ...` to find the unmatched rows.

Comment: The problem is that it's the other way around.

Comment: You're seeing a higher count for the rows? In that case there must be duplicates in the sys.indexes table. Change the query I posted about to a right join and you should see them.